# moreNavigationController reload tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

in swift 1.2 I use this code to reload morenavigationcontroller tableview:

```
(tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController?.view as! UITableView).reloadData()
```

after migrated to Swift 2 I get this error and cannot find a solution:

> Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x11281d1c8) to 'UITableView'
>   (0x11281dbf0).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to the version of Swift but rather to the version of iOS.

Indeed, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/moreNavigationController) says that the `moreNavigationController` is a `UINavigationController` and not a `UINavigationController` whose `topViewController`'s view is a `UITableView.
Therefore Apple can change the implementation and the view hierarchy whenever they want.

You should never rely on such assumptions because your code may crash even in minor updates. So, be careful doing that.

Comment: I get same error in iOS 8.x not only in 9.0. Anyway I found a workaround setting moreTableView = tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController!.view as! UITableView  when I create my custom morenavcontroller and when I need to reload it I call moreTableView.reloadData()